# Is it possible to change language for weather widgets from weather.com?

Tags: javascript

I want change language for weather widgets that provide by [weather.com](http://www.weather.com/) site provides

The generated code for the widgets is:

```
 <script type=\"text/javascript\">

   /* Locations can be edited manually by updating 'wx_locID' below.  Please also update */
   /* the location name and link in the above div (wx_module) to reflect any changes made. */
   var wx_locID = 'SAXX0017';

   /* If you are editing locations manually and are adding multiple modules to one page, each */
   /* module must have a unique div id.  Please append a unique # to the div above, as well */
   /* as the one referenced just below.  If you use the builder to create individual modules  */
   /* you will not need to edit these parameters. */
   var wx_targetDiv = 'wx_module_9421';

   /* Please do not change the configuration value [wx_config] manually - your module */
   /* will no longer function if you do.  If at any time you wish to modify this */
   /* configuration please use the graphical configuration tool found at */
   /* https://registration.weather.com/ursa/wow/step2 */
   var wx_config='SZ=300x250*WX=FHW*LNK=SSNL*UNT=C*BGI=sun*MAP=me|null*DN=www.top2top.net*TIER=0*PID=1309975798*MD5=34d989859d8c0614f3af42405cb4d631';

   document.write('<scr'+'ipt src=\"'+document.location.protocol+'//wow.weather.com/weather/wow/module/'+wx_locID+'?config='+wx_config+'&proto='+document.location.protocol+'&target='+wx_targetDiv+'\"></scr'+'ipt>');  
</script>
```

is this possible ?

Comment: I checked the weather.com code generator by I can't find any option to customize the language of the generated script.